# Custom Code Templates for SuiteCloud IDE

Tags: ide, netsuite

I'm planning on making my own Code Templates for when I generate my new scripts. Since SuiteCloud IDE is only configured for SuiteScript 1.0, I was hoping to create new templates for SuiteScript 2.0.

That said, I've got to the part where I can specify the directory for my custom templates, and I've gone ahead and created my templates, however, since I'm lacking the templates.xml, SuiteCloud IDE doesn't recognise my custom templates.

NetSuite Help doesn't really help that much except state that that file exists. But it doesn't say what it should contain, or even the structure of the data.

If anyone can help out here, it'd be much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've done the same exercise long ago for SuiteScript 1.0, and I've just recently done it for our SuiteScript 2.0 set.

You can find the default templates inside of *P2_POOL_HOME/plugins/com.netsuite.ide.core_2016.2.0.e4.jar/templates/* where `P2_POOL_HOME` is usually *~/.p2/pool/*

The general format of templates.xml is:

```
<configuration>
    <templates>
        <template label="TEXT YOU WANT IN DROPDOWN"
                defaultFilename="DEFAULT NAME FOR FILE"
                typesControl="radio|checkbox"
                headerFilename="PATH/TO/FILE/HEADER"
                startFilename="PATH/TO/START/FILE"
                endFilename="PATH/TO/END/FILE"
                rename="false">
            <types>
                <files label="TEXT LABEL FOR CHECKBOX" bodyFilename="PATH/TO/FILE/WHEN/SELECTED" />
            </types>
        </template>
    </templates>
</configuration>
```

Here are two examples from our templates:

```
<configuration>
    <templates>
        <template label="2.0 Portlet"
                defaultFilename="360CUSTOMER_PROJECT_PL_DESCRIPTION.js"
                typesControl="radio"
                headerFilename="header.ss2.js"
                startFilename="portlet_start.ss2.js"
                endFilename="portlet_end.ss2.js"
                rename="false">
            <types>
                <files label="Render" bodyFilename="portlet.ss2.js" />
            </types>
        </template>

        <template label="2.0 RESTlet"
            defaultFilename="360CUSTOMER_PROJECT_RECORDTYPE_RL_DESCRIPTION.js"
                typesControl="checkbox" headerFilename="header.ss2.js"
                startFilename="RESTlet_start.ss2.js"
                endFilename="RESTlet_end.ss2.js"
                rename="true">
            <types>
                <files label="GET" bodyFilename="RESTlet_get.ss2.js" />
                <files label="POST" bodyFilename="RESTlet_post.ss2.js" />
                <files label="PUT" bodyFilename="RESTlet_put.ss2.js" />
                <files label="DELETE" bodyFilename="RESTlet_delete.ss2.js" />
            </types>
        </template>
    </templates>
</configuration>
```

For scripts that only have one entry point method (e.g. Suitelet, Portlet, Scheduled), you use `radio` for the `typesControl` setting and just have a single `<file>` tag under `<types>`. For those that have multiple entry points to choose from (e.g. Client, Map/Reduce, User Event), you use `checkbox` for the `typesControl` and then list each option that you want using `<file>` tags under `<types>`.

I do not actually know what the `rename` setting does.

The basic file structure of the generated file will be:

```
/* CONTENTS OF HEADER FILE */

/* CONTENTS OF START FILE */

/* CONTENTS OF ENTRY POINT 1 FILE */

/* CONTENTS OF ENTRY POINT 2 FILE */

/* ... */

/* CONTENTS OF ENTRY POINT N FILE */

/* CONTENTS OF END FILE */
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the same thing using 2017. You will find some js and template files inside the jar file. I have modified the ss_2.0_suitelet.js and ss_header.js file.
Just pick those file from the jar and place in your own local library. Then modify. Dont forget to point the template directory in the preference->netsuite (eclipse ide).
You can also add Author and the Date. But not sure how to add the $filename in the comment as variable. Here is some sample.

```
Version    Date            Author            Remarks
1.00       ${date}         ${author}         Initial version
```

Comment: I did update the Code template preferences. But my template doesn't load from local library. Can you help with exact steps needed